# How to create a ListView and show it's header before the adapter is populated

Tags: android, listview

I have a page with two listviews on it.  One listview has a list of recipes, then when you select a recipe the second listview shows all of the ingredients for that recipe.  Simple, right?

The second listview has a header (shows Amount|Ingredient|Location).  I want to create the listview when the page is first loaded and go ahead and load the header, but I don't want to show anything else in the listview until a recipe is actually selected.

If I don't set the adapter for the listview, the header doesn't show.  If I do set the adapter for the listview, it needs the actual list of data I want to show in it, which I don't have yet.

Is the best way to do this really to create a blank ingredient and an arraylist that has only that ingredient in it and load that list at first?  It seems to work, it's just kind of clunky and I was hoping there was a more elegant solution.

Here's the code for my list, not that I think it should really matter, but just in case.  The stars are where the list of ingredients would go if I had them at this point in the workflow.

```
    final ListView ingredientList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ingredientList);
    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_recipe_ingredient,null);
    final SimpleRecipeIngredientAdapter ingredientAdapter = new SimpleRecipeIngredientAdapter(getActivity(), ******);
    ingredientList.setAdapter(ingredientAdapter);
    ingredientList.addHeaderView(header);
```

Comment: Have you tried with an empty adapter? [Check](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-load-more-data.html). Oh sorry, I see now that you are passing a null as your list and that pretty much sums up the solution I provide.

Comment: How can you maintain Two ListView in one screen ? not sure but might be bad practice or design. You can use ListView with section header ...

Comment: It's bad design to have two side by side list views?

One is a long vertical scrolling list you select a recipe from one of like 50-100 recipes.  The other is a 2-6 element list that rarely scrolls and just displays the ingredients.  How is that bad design?

This is for a tablet app with tons of screen real estate, not a phone app.